# Self-hosted blog with Postgres backend

Tags: untagged

I am looking for open-source, free, self-hosted solution for a blog.

I had a look at Wordpress but it's a turn off since it does not support Postgres.

Are there any good blog engines with postgres support?

Comment: Can we ask why it has to support postgres? Why not use SQL?

Comment: @James, SQL is a language, Postgresql is a RDBMS that uses SQL

Comment: @James: Postgres *is* an SQL based database. If you are meaning "why no use mySQL": he may be familiar with prostgres administration and have it installed for other services, and would prefer not to run two RDBMSs (Postgres and MySQL) instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Serendipity comes with Postgres support: http://www.s9y.org/
Drupal also works with Postgresql, but it's a bit oversized for a blog.
Or you could also use a framework like Django or Rails with a blog engine (more difficult to set up) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82653/is-there-any-list-of-blog-engines-written-in-django / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807670/blog-engine-for-rails-application